# @Html.CheckBoxFor Set Value With Value From Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I set the value  of this checkbox with the value of SelectedWebSite1URL property?

```
@model  WLWeb.Models.MyModel
...
    <label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MyModel.SelectedWebSite1, new { @id = "chk1", @class = "chkWebSite", value = "HowDoIsetThis?" })@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyModel.SelectedWebSite1Name)</label>
```

model:

```
public class MyModel
{
...
        public bool SelectedWebSite1 { get; set; }

        public string SelectedWebSite1Name { get; set; }

        public string SelectedWebSite1URL { get; set; }
}
```

Note: the reason I need this is to get the value (website url) with jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnGoSite').click(function () {
        $('.chkWebSite:checked').each(function () {
            alert(this.value);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the page's `@Model`? If the model is set up correctly, it should not be necessary to specify a value explicitly. If you really want to set it explicitly, use the page's `Model` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Remove MyModel

```
  <label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SelectedWebSite1, new { @id = "chk1", @class =  "chkWebSite", value = "yourvaluehere?" })
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SelectedWebSite1Name)</label>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I need. I need to figure out how to set the value of the checkbox with the value of SelectedWebSite1URL property from the model.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misunderstanding a `checkbox`. A `checkbox` is for boolean values (`true` or `false`) not strings.

It works for `public bool SelectedWebSite1 { get; set; }` but not for `public string SelectedWebSite1URL { get; set; }`

If you want to access `SelectedWebSite1URL`, render its value in hidden input and use something like (assumes the hidden input is immediately after the checkbox)

```
$(function () {
  $('#btnGoSite').click(function () {
    $('.chkWebSite:checked').each(function () {
        alert($(this).next('input[type="hidden"]').val());
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<label>

    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.SelectedWebSite1,new { @id = "chk1", @class = "chkWebSite"})

    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyModel.SelectedWebSite1Name)
 </label>
```

No need to set value in html object attributes as check box will be automatically check/uncheck based on value of SelectedWebSite1 is true/false.

Comment: He is asking for setting value attribute of checkbox. for instance: val="1" or val="apple"